# jQuery removeClass on button click only if not focused (blur won't work in this scenrio)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background: I have a Java web app and a simple form with required fields that posts via ajax and I have label styling that requires adding and removing a class on input focus and blur to the closest parent `<div>` or `<td>` of the label if the input has no value entered which all works fine.

When the form posts, the added focus class is still there but I am able to remove it by having a click event on the submit button with a 400ms delay.

The problem is that on that button click to submit, if a required field is empty there is another event that auto focuses the required field to let you know you must enter text there so on that required auto focus it adds the the class as it's supposed to but then removes it after the 400ms settimeout from the button click. I need to only remove that focus class on a successful ajax submit or only if there is no focus on the input.

Here's a simple example of what I have currently. With just one input and submit button to illustrate.

HTML

```
<div id="locationField">
    <label>Start Address</label>
    <input type="text" required/>
</div>
<input id="post_btn" type="image" src="img/submit.png"/>
```

JS

```
//addClass on focus
$("input[type='text']").focus(function(){
  $(this).closest('div, td').addClass("focusActive");
});

//removeClass on blur
$("input[type='text']").blur(function()
{
    if(!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).closest('div, td').removeClass("focusActive");
    }
});

//button click to removeClass
$("#post_btn").click(function(){
  setTimeout(
      function() {
        if(!$("#locationField input[type='text']").val() ) {
            $("#locationField").removeClass("focusActive");
        }
      },
      400);
});
```

Comment: You must have code that actually makes the ajax call all the way at the end when all validation is done and dandy.. why not remove your classes then?

Comment: The whole system itself is a bit complex and someone else worked on the ajax stuff so I'm just trying to accomplish this with added JS/Jquery in my JS file which doesn't have any of the ajax

Comment: To stop the "second" validation upon the button click, add the `novalidate` attribute to the `<form>` element containing the `<input>` element. Plus, can you clarify why you are searching every single `<td>` in the document? Since the `<div>` you are attempting to affect is a parent, is the a reason you chose not to use `.parents()`? Finally, you don't show any `<td>` in your HTML, so context is sort of lost in your sample.

Comment: The reason it searches every div or td is to apply that class to the closest one to the label, mainly for other forms in the system and the way their html structure is on other pages and .parents didn’t work in some cases so this way seemed to work for all